# How to change the code that if isAutomatic true then scale up down automatic and if isAutomatic false use the G key to fade in out?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;
    public bool isAutomatic = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) || isAutomatic)
        {
            scaleUp = !scaleUp;

            if (scaleCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

            if (scaleUp)
            {
                scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
            }

            else
            {
                scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
            }

            isAutomatic = false;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj,
        Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            yield return null;
        }

        isAutomatic = true;
    }
}
```

now if isAutomatic false when i press the G key once then the object will scale up down automatic.

and if isAutomatic true then it will scake up down automatic without pressing the G key at all.

and if i'm not using the isAutomatic flag then i can use the G key to scale up down.

but i want another mode , that if isAutomatic true automatic scale up down but if it's false then only use the G key.

I tried this but then if isAutomatic true the object that scale up down start scaling up but then stop trying to scale up/down and stuck cant scale up and cant scale down like stuck in the middle trying to scale up/down the same time :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;
    public bool isAutomatic = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            Fade();
        }

        if(isAutomatic)
        {
            Fade();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj,
        Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private void Fade()
    {
        scaleUp = !scaleUp;

        if (scaleCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

        if (scaleUp)
        {
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
        }

        else
        {
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working , using the isAutomatic flag and another flag helper automatic.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;
    public bool isAutomatic = false;

    private bool automatic = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            Fade();
        }

        if (isAutomatic && automatic)
        {
            Fade();

            automatic = false;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj,
        Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            yield return null;
        }

        automatic = true;
    }

    private void Fade()
    {
        scaleUp = !scaleUp;

        if (scaleCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

        if (scaleUp)
        {
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
        }

        else
        {
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could get rid of the additional flag by reusing one field you already have: `if (scaleCoroutine != null) { StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine); scaleCoroutine = null; }` and then `if (isAutomatic && scaleCoroutine == null)`